# Python IndexError: list index out of range when implementing covariance from scratch

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, matrix, covariance

I'm trying to implement covariance from scratch. It's raising a `IndexError: list index out of range` error. What does it mean and how can I change my code?

Data source: https://www.kaggle.com/adepvenugopal/graduate-admission-data?select=Admission_Predict.csv

I calculated the `mean` and `standard deviation` before implementing the `covariance` matrix.

Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Admission_Predict.csv')
df = df.sample(frac=1)


# Correlation matrix
mat = df.to_numpy()
cov = []


# Mean
for a in range(len(mat)):
    mean_list = []
    mean = sum([_ for _ in mat[a]]) / len(mat)
    mean_list.append(mean)

# Standard deviation
for b in range(len(mat)):
    stdev = sum([(_-mean)**2 for _ in mat[b]]) / (len(mat[b])-1)

# Covariance matrix
for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
    for k in range(mat.shape[1]):

        # Random variables
        var = (((mat[i][j] - mean_list[j]) * (mat[i][k] - mean_list[k])) for i in range(mat.shape[1]))

        # Covariance
        covariance = sum(var) / (len(mat) - 1)
        print(covariance)
```

Traceback error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod2.py", line 30, in
> <module>
>     covariance = sum(var) / (len(mat) - 1)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod2.py", line 27, in
> <genexpr>
>     var = (((mat[i][j] - mean_list[j]) * (mat[i][k] - mean_list[k])) for i in range(mat.shape[1])) IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Check that the variable `mean` is a scalar or vector.

Comment: `mean` is a scalar. Since `sum` and `len` both produce a single value, that means that `mean = sum([_ for _ in mat[a]]) / len(mat)` is also only a single value. The for loop calculates all the means but only the last one is saved in the variable. A collection like a `list` could be helpful if looking to store them all.

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for the suggestion. I've implemented a `mean_list` but its now raising `IndexError: list index out of range`. Please check the edited question above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the size of `mat`. I added `print(mat.shape)` behind `mat = df.to_numpy()` and found the `mat` is a matrix(400,8),like the dataframe. The loops use the `len(mat)`(it's a scalar,=400) as index ,so in the loop for computing covariance, the index will be out of range. (it's 400*8,but the loop use 400,400).
Also, the `mean` is a scalar, it's the mean of all the numbers in the `mat`. len(mean_list) is 1.
You may try to use a tuple to store the shape vale of the mat,and use them in the loop,or use `for j in range(mat.shape[1])`in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've edited my code in the question above and used `for j in range(mat.shape[1])` but its still raising the `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

Comment: `var = (((mat[i][j] - mean_list[j]) * (mat[i][k] - mean_list[k])) for i in range(mat.shape[1]))`, because `len(mean_list)` is 1(it's a scalar, the mean of the matrix),mean_list[j],mean_list[k] are both out of range. You may change them into mean_list[0].

Comment: `k` also need to change to `for k in range(mat.shape[1])`

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe for i loop should be the outside one? The result is 400,400 matrix or 8,8 matrix?